# What is the semantic difference between TechnicalCommittee and Council in kusama/polkadot?

Tags: pallet-collective

```rust
construct_runtime! {
 Council:            pallet_collective::<Instance1>::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Origin<T>, Event<T>, Config<T>},
 TechnicalCommittee: pallet_collective::<Instance2>::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Origin<T>, Event<T>, Config<T>},
}
```

There seems to be two instances of `pallet_collective` in the `substrate-node` and it has me wondering why? What is the purpose of a `council`, and what is the purpose of a `technical committee` and how are they different from each other?

Answer (score 2):

From a high-level view this is the Council:

- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-governance#council

This is the Technical Committee:

- https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-governance#technical-committee

Note that:

> Teams are added or removed from the Technical Committee via a simple majority vote of the Council.